# How to add text label to a MapMarker? MapViewPins have poor perfomance apparently

Tags: flutter, here-api

I'd like to add custom markers with text labels on my map. I can use MapViewPins for this, but they "tremble" when map is being moved. Even one MapViewPin behaves like this in [official Here example](https://github.com/heremaps/here-sdk-examples/tree/master/examples/latest/navigate/flutter/map_items_app), so it is probably not an optimization issue.

When i load PNG image and use it as a MapMarker, it works perfectly. But i don't know how to add text to a marker.

I am using Here SDK for Flutter (Navigate Edition) 4.12.4.0 with Flutter 3.3.2

GIF below is an example. Cyan circles are MapMarkers, markers with icons and label are MapViewPins. Is there any solution to this problem?

[image]

Comment: So you want a marker with text labels to show on Google_Maps?

Comment: Its not Google Maps. It is maps from Here.com

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the MapViewPins, being widgets embedded in the MapView surface, need to be relocated to the fixed coordinates every time the map is interacted with by gestures, which is why you notice this "strange" behavior.

However, what you mention about using MapMarkers would be the best solution but in this case instead of using PNG files, you could use SVG files in which you enter the text you want to display.

There is currently no other way available to do what you mention using the HERE SDK (Navigate Edition).

Here is a link to our most up-to-date HERE SDK (Navigate Edition) documentation: https://developer.here.com/documentation/flutter-sdk-navigate/dev_guide/index.html